# Targeting Only the Parent 'li' and ignoring Other CHildren 'li's'

Tags: jquery, navigation, html-lists

I know that I am close to getting this sorted but I am sure there is a better way to achieve the following:

I want to target 'li's' that have a child 'ul' and append a span like this:

```
<li class="parent">
 <a>Item 1 <span> </span></a>

  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Here is the jQuery I am trying to use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('ul').attr("id", "nav");
jQuery("ul#nav li:has(ul)").addClass("hasChildren");    
if (jQuery('ul#nav li.hasChildren').length)
{
    jQuery('ul#nav li.hasChildren a').append("<span></span>");
}
});
```

The problem is that a span gets added to all of the 'li's' regardless if they have a sub ul in them or not.

So my question is how to add a span to ONLY the li's that have a sub ul in them and not to all of the li's

Gary

Comment: **FYI**, `jQuery('ul').attr("id", "nav");` is giving every `ul` on your page the id of `nav`. As ids are supposed to be unique, you're probably after something like `jQuery('ul').first().attr("id", "nav");`

Comment: Also, the code you've posted [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/mattlunn/XB5gs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code is with this selector `ul#nav li:has(ul)`. It will look for all the `li` elements inside `ul#nav`. If you want to just look for the child elements then you should use `ul#nav > li:has(ul)`. Try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('ul:first').attr("id", "nav");
   jQuery("ul#nav > li:has(ul)").addClass("hasChildren");    
   if (jQuery('ul#nav li.hasChildren').length)
   {
       jQuery('ul#nav li.hasChildren a').append("<span></span>");
   }
});
```

Simplified version of your code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('ul:first').attr("id", "nav");
   jQuery("#nav > li:has(ul) li").append("<a>...<span>..</span> </a>");
   }
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with that selector? It's looking for all `li` elements which contain a `ul`, which is exactly what the OP is after.

Comment: @Matt - He is looking for the child elements which has `ul` in it. If you dont specify to look only in child elements then it will look for all the li's. Hope you understand this and remove your down vote.

Comment: yeah but this is something for the OP to decide, i'm guessing the span is showing a little arrow (submenu available or something)
so it is possible he has multi level submenus, so not only the first level should be selected...

that said, doesn't your selector appends the a + span to the li's inside the li's having a sub ul? shouldn't it append to the LI itself instead of its sub LI's?

your selector in simplified version should be : jQuery("#nav > li:has(ul)").append(...);

Comment: @Sander - `#nav > li:has(ul)` will select all `li`'s which have `ul` in it. I will not select the `li`'s of the `ul`. So we have to use `#nav > li:has(ul) li` to get all the `li`'s of the inner `ul`.

Comment: true, that is what i'm saying, he does not seek to target the inner li's he wants to append a span in the link of the container li. (a span which i expect will indicate 'submenu available' with a little arrow or something )

Comment: Ok, ... this almost worked as you gave it. I changed some of the code using some of the answers below and found a way that works.  `jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('#navigation ul:first').attr("id", "nav");
 jQuery("ul#nav li:has(ul)").addClass("hasChildren"); 
 if (jQuery('ul#nav li.hasChildren > a').length)
 {
  jQuery('ul#nav li.hasChildren > a').append("<span></span>");
 }
});`

Answer (score 1):

The `ul#nav li.hasChildren a` selector is selecting all descendant `a` elements. If you just want to select for direct child elements, use `ul#nav li.hasChildren > a`.

Comment: Here is what I found to work ... `jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('#navigation ul:first').attr("id", "nav");
 jQuery("ul#nav li:has(ul)").addClass("hasChildren"); 
 if (jQuery('ul#nav li.hasChildren > a').length)
 {
  jQuery('ul#nav li.hasChildren > a').append("<span></span>");
 }
});`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("li ul:first").before("<a>Item 1 <span> </span></a>");
```

It will select the first `ul` in each `li`, and add that text right before it.